# How to restrict a match to a specific string in a column of a record?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file of 2000 lines containing following results:

```
> HGNC:24239 |  2   | deleterious_low_confidence(0.01) 
> HGNC:6583  |  1   | deleterious(0.04)
```

I want to get just those lines with the *deleterious()* not *deleterious_low_confidence()*. I used this command but didn't work:

```
awk 'NR==1; $3 ~ /^deleterious(*)$/' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my command?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are about three things that makes your command,

```
awk 'NR==1; $3 ~ /^deleterious(*)$/' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

not work as expected:

1. The input field separator in the data is `|`.  The default separator (which you are using) is any collection of spaces or tabs.  This means that `$3` would be the first `|` character on each line.
2. The `NR==1` bit of your code would cause the first line to be printed, no matter what.
3. The regular expression that you use contains a expression error.  `(` and `)` are special in extended regular expressions, and needs to be escaped.  However `deleterious\(*\)` would also not work as `\(*` matches "any number of `(` characters".

To correctly use `|` as the input field separator, use `awk` with `-F '|'`.  In this case though, you might want to use `[[:blank:]]*\\|[[:blank:]]*` to make it also include the flanking spaces/tabs around the pipe symbols (if there are any).  The backslashes in front of `|` are needed to make it a literal pipe symbol (the field separator is treated as a regular expression if it's longer than a single character, and `|` does alternation in regular expressions).  The expression `[[:blank:]]*[|][[:blank:]]*` would also work as `|` would be literal within `[...]`.

To match the third field against `deleterious(<anything>)` we can use the expression `^deleterious\(.*\)$`.  The parentheses also need to be escaped since they are special in regular expressions. Alternatively, `^deleterious[(].*[)]$` could be used.

This means that you would use

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*[|][[:blank:]]*' '$3 ~ /^deleterious\(.*\)$/' file1.txt >file2.txt
```

With the given data, this would produce

```
> HGNC:6583  |  1   | deleterious(0.04)
```

in `file2.txt`.

With a *single* `|` as the field separator, you could use

```
awk -F '|' '$3 ~ /^[[:blank:]]*deleterious\(.*\)$/' file1.txt >file2.txt
```

and in that way allow for the existence of spaces or tabs at the start of the third field.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `fgrep`:

```
fgrep 'deleterious(' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

If you want to use `awk`, you need a proper regular expression:

```
awk -F '|' '$3 ~ /^ deleterious\(.*\)$/' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

or

```
awk -F ' \| ' '$3 ~ /^deleterious\(.*\)$/' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

or

```
awk '$6 ~ /^deleterious\(.*\)$/' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Comment: Note the space at the start of the third field in the input data

Comment: @Kusalananda I added two possible solutions for the leading space.

Comment: Dear RalfFriedl, thanks but still doesn't work. In my file there are whitespace between columns instead of   ' | '.  I left it empty  -F ' '  , but still doen't work. It returns empty file. Could you please help me out?

Comment: Note that `-F ''` is not the same as omitting `-F` If you don't specify a field separator, your field number is six. If non of these work, find out what characters exactly separate your columns.